# Mapping tables to two inherited tables in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, database-design

I am trying to map a set of tables that have a complicated relationship between them. I have the following tables with fields:

```
Table: Parent
       id
       type

Table: Child1
       parentId : foreign
       list of fields

Table: Child2
       parentId : foreign
       list of fields
```

In the database the basic idea is that the Parent tables type field determines whether a related record occurs in Child1 or Child2. In this way I store information about the record depending on its type e.g. they are all customers but some are individuals and some are businesses so I can store separate information depending on this.

My question is how do I model this in Hibernate? I know to use @SecondaryTable to merge two tables but how do I do this dependant on a value in the parent table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is using a discriminator column for the class. See [Hibernate docs re  inheritance mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#inheritance-mixing-tableperclass-tablepersubclass)

The example is

```
<class name="Payment" table="PAYMENT">
    <id name="id" type="long" column="PAYMENT_ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="PAYMENT_TYPE" type="string"/>
    <property name="amount" column="AMOUNT"/>
    ...
    <subclass name="CreditCardPayment" discriminator-value="CREDIT">
        <join table="CREDIT_PAYMENT">
            <property name="creditCardType" column="CCTYPE"/>
            ...
        </join>
    </subclass>
    <subclass name="CashPayment" discriminator-value="CASH">
        ...
    </subclass>
    <subclass name="ChequePayment" discriminator-value="CHEQUE">
        ...
    </subclass>
</class>
```

Comment: This looks great thanks. Could you explain how to do this with annotations as well? would be good to learn

Comment: @Michael: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168

Comment: Not being sadist or anything but I've been told to take the discriminator from an id which is foreign from another table with a description in it. Any idea how this might work?

Comment: I only leant the XML way - mainly as I design the DB first and generate the POJOS - Looking at https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/ANN-140 looks like you can't - but using joins do you need the discriminator column.

Comment: @Michael Allen - I would ask that as a separe question as I would like to see the whole relevant schema laid out